# How to kill locked mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating and testing a mysql join query but each time so far it causes the database tables to lockup and the site hangs. I have to then call the host and they kill the locked queries. 
Is this something I can do from phpmyadmin so not to bother them while I tweak the script to work? Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done from the front page of phpMyAdmin.  Look for the "Processes" link.

You can also run the command `SHOW PROCESSLIST` (or `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`).  This will show you all the queries that you are able to manipulate (i.e. your own).  Along with each query will be an identifier.  You can issue the `KILL` command to any of those identifiers to kill the query.

Also, you should consider testing your query with `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about phpMyAdmin but the free "mysql tools" package contains an application called **MySql Adminstrator** that lets you do just this. It shows you currently running queries and provides a kill thread button (this is in the server health tab I believe).

Mysql GUI Tools/ Mysql Workbench are far superior to phpMyAdmin anyway. If you're running the database locally, or have ssh access, there's really no reason to use phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Great advice thanks. I will install that locally and try testing there first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall a way to do it from phpmyadmin. You might try testing your query on a local test copy database rather than live so that you get better throughput, until it no longer locks up.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is through mytop, hit "k"  and enter the thread id you want to kill.

```
   Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time    Cmd    State Query                                                                                                                
   --      ----         -------         --       ----    ---    ----- ----------
```