# mysql phpmyadmin dropped table timed out and now will not open nor is deleted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

From phpmyadmin I tried to empty a large table
It took forever and eventually timed out
phpmyadmin would not open again until I cleared my cache

After I got it back open all of the tables will open except for the table I tried to empty
(I also can not run a php script on that table)

Is there a way to run a cleanup on this table? (I can't click it on phpmyadmin)
I am fine with the table being deleted if possible (I had the data backed up in a different named table and would just rename this table)

What do I do??

Comment: just found the processes tab - there are a bunch of things in there including my empty it says waiting for table can I click kill?

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin has access to the active processes

The request got hung up and the process was able to be killed

[How to kill locked mysql queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710911/how-to-kill-locked-mysql-queries)